# Hot Reloading - preventing browser from crashing on errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I am trying to create some hot reloading functionality for browser based JS. All is going very well except one problem - when I am editing a file on the filesystem and the browser loads the new file, if the file contains syntax/reference errors or whatever, the browser will crash, unrecoverably. This limits the benefits of hot reloading, because anytime you make changes that contain errors, the browser will crash and your hot loading bliss is over and you have to do a browser refresh to recover, which defeats the purpose of the whole thing.

So, in order to make hot reloading most useful, upon an error in the browser, I could fix the problem in my file and then the hot loader would reload the improved file and the browser could *recover*.

Is there any way to show an error message in the browser without getting into an unrecoverable state upon a runtime error?

I was able to get most of the functionality I want like so:

```
  window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {

        alert(errorMsg+'\n\nurl:'+url+ '\n\nLine number:'+lineNumber);
        return true;

    };
```

unfortunately, this didn't work, it brought me into unrecoverable

```
  window.onerror = function myErrorHandler(errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {

        var html = "<div>" +errorMsg+'\n\nurl:'+url+ '\n\nLine number:'+lineNumber +"</div>"
        $('body').html(html);
        return true;

    };
```

it looks like any DOM manipulation will prevent you from recovering your program, but that might be an oversimplification - anyone know what's going on? I'd rather avoid alert messages that lock up the browser and need to be clicked in order to go away.

Perhaps some non-blocking modal dialog will do, as long as it doesn't write to the DOM.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you're able to crash a modern browser with a _SyntaxError_, but one way to test code will work when you're expecting a syntax error in the fail case is `try {eval('code as string');} catch (e) {/* fail case */}`. Don't use this pattern in your final code.

Comment: well, let's say reference error, not syntax error

Comment: how does reference error in autoloaded code differ from reference error in poorly written code (which is unfixable automatically)?